# TrueZip compression taking too much time

Tags: java, compression, truezip

I am using `TrueZip` for compression. Here is what my code looks like

```
  public String compress() throws IOException {
    if (logLocations.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("no logs provided to compress");
    }

    removeDestinationIfExists(desiredArchive);

    final TFile destinationArchive = new TFile(desiredArchive + "/diagnostics");
    for (final String logLocation : logLocations) {
      final TFile log = new TFile(logLocation);
      if (!log.exists()) {
        LOGGER.debug("{} does not exist, ignoring.");
        continue;
      }
      if (log.isDirectory()) {
        log.cp_r(destinationArchive);
      } else {
        final String newLogLocation =
            new TFile(destinationArchive.getAbsolutePath()) + SLASH +
            getLogNameFromPath(logLocation);
        log.cp(new TFile(newLogLocation));
      }
    }
    return destinationArchive.getEnclArchive().getAbsolutePath();
  }
```

and my test

```
@Test
  public void testBenchMarkWithHprof() throws IOException {
    final FileWriter logLocations;
    String logLocationPath = "/Users/harit/Downloads/tmp/logLocations.txt";
    {
      logLocations = new FileWriter(logLocationPath);
      logLocations.write("Test3");
      logLocations.write("\n");
      logLocations.close();
    }
    final LPLogCompressor compressor = new LPLogCompressor("/Users/harit/Downloads/tmp",
                                                           new File(logLocationPath),
                                                           "/Users/harit/Downloads/tmp/TestOut");
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    compressor.compress();
    System.out.println("Time taken (msec): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
  }
```

and my data directory `Test3` looks like

```
Test3/
      java_pid1748.hprof
```

The file size is `2.83GB`
When I ran the test, it took over **22 minutes**.
However when I compress the same file using `Native OSX compress (right click -> compress)`, it takes only **2 minutes**

Why there is so much of difference?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Based on @Satnam recommendation, I attached a debugger to see whats going on and this is what I find

[image]
[image]

None of the TrueZip Threads are running? really? Apologies I am using profiler for the first time

Comment: why not use a profiler?

Comment: And are there differences - file attributes, like owner and read-only stored? (Testable on a small directory). With standard java means a zip file system can be made, needing only one copy operation with `Files.copy` to copy a directory from the disk into a zip.

Comment: @satnam, I updated the snapshot, do you see diffs?

Comment: @JoopEggen, its exactly the same file, I am confused

Comment: You should be using the sampler or the profiler and take a snapshot. The screens you showed are useless. Maybe do some reading on how to use a profiler and analyze the results yourself before posting them here for us to analyze for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason in this case was using default [Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) which is `Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION`.

I override the `ZipDriver` class to over the level as

```
import de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.ZipDriver;
import de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.IOPoolProvider;

import java.util.zip.Deflater;

public class OverrideZipDriver extends ZipDriver {

  public OverrideZipDriver(final IOPoolProvider ioPoolProvider) {
    super(ioPoolProvider);
  }

  @Override
  public int getLevel() {
    return Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;
  }
}
```

and then in my `Compressor` class, I did

```
public LPLogCompressor(final String logProcessorInstallPath, final File logLocationsSource,
                         final String desiredArchive) throws IOException {
    this.desiredArchive = desiredArchive + DOT + getDateTimeStampFormat() + ZIP;
    logLocations = getLogLocations(logProcessorInstallPath, logLocationsSource);
    enableLogCompression();
  }

  private static void enableLogCompression() {
    TConfig.get().setArchiveDetector(
        new TArchiveDetector(TArchiveDetector.NULL, new Object[][]{
            {"zip", new OverrideZipDriver(IOPoolLocator.SINGLETON)},}));
    TConfig.push();
  }
```

You can read the thread [here](https://java.net/projects/truezip/lists/users/archive/2015-04/message/4)

Comment: You are modifying the (potentially global) configuration before doing the push. Please have a look here for correct usage: https://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TConfig.html#local